# Effect of the independent variables on dependent variable

Tags: regression

I have a data set on student performance on various courses. The dependent variable is the grade of the student. The independent variables include "total study time ", "number of absences", and "access to Internet" which can be changed by the student.

What analysis methods are appropriate to analyze the effect of changing these independent variables (such as increasing the study time, getting an Internet account, etc) on the dependent variable grade.

Comment: Your tag `regression` is already the essence of any answer.  I can't see that you have a new question beyond those under that tag.

Comment: Note that in an observational study you only see associations, not cause and effect.

Answer (score 2):

Given your description, and as Nick Cox stated, a linear regression would be suitable.

The basic model can be stated as:
$$
performance = \beta_0 + \beta_1 studytime + \beta_2 absences + \beta_3 internetaccess + \varepsilon
$$

Given that you have data on multiple classes/classrooms I would add a fixed effect for class and cluster standard errors on class levels.